# When making public key fingerprints - is a sha1 hash still a good idea?

Tags: hash, rsa, public-key

I'm thinking about trying to save some space (and readability) when referencing 2k and 4k public keys (millions of them) by storing the [fingerprint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_fingerprint) in some places instead of the full public key.

> The primary threat to the security of a fingerprint is a preimage attack, where an attacker constructs a key pair whose public key hashes to a fingerprint which matches the victim's fingerprint. The attacker could then present his public key in place of the victim's public key to masquerade as the victim.
>
> A secondary threat to some systems is a collision attack, where an attacker constructs multiple key pairs which hash to his own fingerprint. This may allow an attacker to repudiate signatures he has created, or cause other confusion.
>   - Wikipedia

With this in mind, I was wondering about using a larger hashing algorithm like SHA-256 to help prevent collisions or collision attacks.

SHA1 seems to be the existing standard, but is it still the way to go?

Comment: The known weaknesses in SHA-1 don't matter much since collisions aren't a big threat for fingerprints. So using it is okay. If you don't need compatibility with fingerprints computed by other software SHA-2 is probably a better idea. You can truncate it a bit if you want.

Comment: Assuming Wikipedia is up to date, the most efficient attack against SHA1 [still costs $2.77M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#Attacks) for a single hash. Even if someone mounts a collision attack against you, you can still ask them to sign or encrypt something to verify their identity. From what I understand, you will only be using fingerprints to index keys in your database?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that in 2005 SHA-1 was found to have a security flaw and the now recommended standard for this kind of thing is SHA-2 (256 or 512).

This post may be of some use:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897434/password-security-sha1-sha256-or-sha512

Comment: I'm more interested in collisions, not password security from hashing. Besides, I would use bcrypt for passwords to increase the time needed to hash them.

Comment: I believe the chances of a SHA-1 collision is something like 10^48. Or thereabouts.

Comment: @JonnyWilson $2^{160} \approx 10^{48}$ is the cost of a pre-image attack against SHA-1. A generic collision attack costs $2^{80}$, and thanks to SHA-1's weaknesses a collision attack is even cheaper.

Comment: @Xeoncross The security weakness in SHA-1 is not limited to hashing passwords. They are directly related to an attacker being able to find a message `m2` such that $H(m1) == H(m2) \vert| m1 != m2$, which is exactly the sort of issue that should concern you. It's still too difficult to generate collisions in practice, but the security properties of SHA-1 are only going to get weaker. When developing new software, choosing one of the SHA-2 algorithms is probably prudent.